# Como separar String de edital no Excel

Tags: string, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Preciso separa esse tipo de String (Exemplo):

```
1 Estruturas lógicas. 2 Lógica de argumentação: analogias, inferências, deduções e conclusões. 3 Lógica sentencial (ou proposicional). 3.1 Proposições simples e compostas. 3.2 Tabelasverdade. 3.3 Equivalências. 3.4 Leis de De Morgan. 3.5 Diagramas lógicos. 4 Lógica de primeira ordem. 5 Princípios de contagem e probabilidade. 6 Operações com conjuntos. 7 Raciocínio lógico envolvendo problemas aritméticos, geométricos e matriciais.
```

Quero o que o resultado fique assim, célula abaixo de célula:

```
1 Estruturas lógicas.  

2 Lógica de argumentação: analogias, inferências, deduções e conclusões.  

3 Lógica sentencial (ou proposicional). 

3.1 Proposições simples e compostas. 

3.2 Tabelas-verdade.

3.3 Equivalências.
```

E assim por diante. 
Contudo, não achei uma regra/função para fazer isso no VBA do excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema fui estudar [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) (Regular Expression), mas como estava aprendendo, não consegui criar uma Expressão complexa que resolvesse o problema. Então fui no obter a [resposta no SO Global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46331543/7690982). Créditos: [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

## 1o passo: Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

## 2o passo: Criação do RegEX

Uma [demonstração do regex](https://regex101.com/r/WpiKin/2) pode ser vista, em que a expressão usada é: `\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?[\D]+\.(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))`

Em que a explicação do desenvolvedor deste código é a seguinte:

**Detailhes**

- `\d+` - 1 ou mais dígitos
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - zero ou mais sequências de:

  - `\.` - ponto
  - `\d+` - 1 ou mais dígitos
- `[\s\S]*?` - qualquer 0+ chars, mínimo possível, até o primeiro...
- `\w+\.` - 1 ou mais palavras chars seguidos de `.`
- O `(?=\s*(?:\d+|$))` verificar positivo exige a presença de zero ou mais espaços em branco `(\s*)` seguidos de um ou mais dígitos `(\d+)` ou fim de string `($)` imediatamente à direita do local atual.

## 3o passo: Código VBA

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
str = "1 Estruturas lógicas. 2 Lógica de argumentação: analogias, inferências, deduções e conclusões. 3 Lógica sentencial (ou proposicional). 3.1 Proposições simples e compostas. 3.2 Tabelasverdade. 3.3 Equivalências. 3.4 Leis de De Morgan. 3.5 Diagramas lógicos. 4 Lógica de primeira ordem. 5 Princípios de contagem e probabilidade. 6 Operações com conjuntos. 7 Raciocínio lógico envolvendo problemas aritméticos, geométricos e matriciais."
Set objRegExp = New regexp ' CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D\.(?=\s*(?:\d|$))"
objRegExp.Global = True
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
  For Each m In objMatches
      Debug.Print m.Value
  Next
End If
```

Com saída do `Debug.Print` de:

[image: Saída Imediata]

#### Nota

O RegEx estava usando qualquer letra `[a-zA-Z]` seguida de um ponto para determinar o fim de um item da lista. Mas no caso de acabar com `).` não era reconhecido, portanto, foi alterada de qualquer letra para qualquer não-dígito `\D`.

> Note que `\D` combina qualquer símbolo não-dígito. Você pode querer usar 
>   `\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D\.(?=\s*(?:\d|$))`. E para o `^`, Ele pode combinar
>   começo da String (com RegExp.Multiline = False), ou iniciar a linha
>   (com RegExp.Multiline = True) – Wiktor Stribiżew 5 hours ago
>
> E outra dica: Se não há quebras de linha na string, `[\s\S]` pode
>   ser substituído por `.` – Wiktor Stribiżew 4 hours ago

- Um novo teste foi realizado com a nova expressão e pode ser [vista aqui](https://regex101.com/r/mV3seF/1). **Em que a nova expressão foi substituída no código numa edição desta resposta:**

  ```
  objRegExp.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D\.(?=\s*(?:\d|$))"
  ```
- Caso ocorra o erro, **Erro de compilação: O tipo definido pelo usuário não foi definido.** E esta linha esteja grifada: `Set objRegExp = New regexp ' CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`

  Descomente o código CreateObject e delete New regex, deste modo:`Set objRegExp =  CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`

#### Implementar em céluas

Um Breve código para implementar em uma planilha do Excel. Para alocar estes valores em células basta trabalhar com o valor `m.Value`

Assumindo a string na célula A1 e os valores serão inseridos a partir da célula B1 até B última linha.

```
Dim str As String
Dim objMatches As Object
Dim i As Long: Let i = 1
str = Cells(1, 1)
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)*[\s\S]*?\D\.(?=\s*(?:\d|$))"
objRegExp.Global = True
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
  For Each m In objMatches
      Cells(i, 2) = m.Value
      i = i + 1
  Next
End If
```